# How to fix the screen blackout in an HP Pavilion dv7-1240us

Tags: laptop, display, battery

Many users of the HP Pavilion dv71240-us have had this screen blackout problem. After having the laptop on for a few minutes the screen goes black and there is no way to get it back to normal.

Many have blamed the battery, others that the laptop gets too hot and have looked for ways to cool it down. I used a cooler with 5 fans but it did not work.

My solution was to remove the battery and use the laptop only with the power adaptor. Of course I cannot recharge the battery while the laptop is on but at least it does not go black and forces to restart it.

I have to choose between using it with a battery and not with the adaptor or use it with only the adaptor.

If anyone has been dealing with this problem and found a solution that not even HP can provide, I'll be very grateful.

Comment: Have you done a hard reset? If the problem persists more than likely it is a bios issue, [HP has a bios update for your model](http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-Pavilion-dv7-1200-Entertainment-Notebook-PC-series/3837623/model/3860621#Z7_3054ICK0KGTE30AQO5O3KA30R1), bios updates are risky, be warned it can brick your HP in rare cases.